# mipmaps not works properly. See Android default icon

Tags: android, mipmaps

I am using `mipmaps` for my `ic_launcher` icons but I am having some problems using it.

When I install application on my device, I can see correct icon but if I go to settings and then to application installed list. The icon image of my application is the Android default one... why ?

**SOLVED**:
Use `drawable`

Comment: What happens, if you use `drawable`, instead of `mipmaps`?

Comment: I need to try, yesterday evening I have not tested but I think that this will works as all my other applications. But I don't like to use drawable and mipmaps for ic_launcher...both

Comment: I didn't mean "both". I meant ONLY drawable.

Comment: Ok this is easy but if I need to use drawable...why mipmap was created if doesn't works properly ??

Comment: Nobody knows... Only Google. As when they mangled the AlarmManager or the permission system... They have a lot of fun in complicating our lives. But I don't use mipmaps and live well!

Comment: eheheh, you are right Bob

Comment: Turned my comment to an answer, so that you can accept it and remove this post from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Answer (score 0):

Turned from a comment to an answer, since it solved the issue:
Simply use `drawable`, instead of `mipmaps`